# Aws Lambda: Missing export menu

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on aws lambda and trying to export a selected function but it does not show export function menu in a particular region. In other regions it shows export function menu.

I wonder how and what changes should be made to have export function menu?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that not all AWS consoles on all regions support exporting of functions via AWS consoles. You may try using AWS CLI instead and issue the `lambda get-function` command.

```bash
aws lambda get-function --function-name my-function --query 'Code.Location'
```

This CLI command will respond with a pre-signed S3 url that could be used to download to retrieve the function's codebase in a zip file.

If you are dealing with a function with container configuration, you will be able to download the container from the container registry associated with your function.

```bash
# Replace the URI with your function's image URI
docker pull aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazonlinux:latest
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that other functions that did not have Export menu were deployed as a container image. Is it possible to download files in some way?

Comment: @mrd, can you share your SAM or CDK template? You can also run this command to view the image URI `aws lambda get-function --function-name my-function`

Comment: Yes I see ImageUri and ResolvedImageUri. How to use this uri? When used in browser, it prompts for username and password. My normal credentials do not work. What permissions are required to access it by another user who did not create this image?

Comment: @mrd, you need the ImageUri, find the docker repository (Maybe an ECR in your case) and download it using this command `docker pull aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazonlinux:latest` (Replace the URL with what you got from the CLI)